# Convergence of improper integral $\int_0^1 t^p \sin t dt$

Tags: improper-integrals

Need help with this problem. For $p\in \mathbb{R}$ consider the improper integral
$$I_p=\int_0^1 t^p \sin t dt$$
Which of the following is statements are true regarding the convergence of $I_p$?

A. $I_p$ is convergent for $p=-1/2$ 
B. $I_p$ is divergent for $p=-3/2$ 
C. $I_p$ is convergent for $p=-4/3$ 
D. $I_p$ is divergent for $p=-1/2$

First of all, I could not understand why is it improper. Secondly the answer is provided as all correct. But could not get explanation for that either. Can you guide me please ? Tried to search in MSE to get any answer for that, but in vain. If anywhere it is showed how to solve, please help me to get the link. I will study my self and try to understand.

Comment: How can both A and D be true simultaneously?

Comment: @sudeep5221I am searching myself the answer.

Comment: The integral is improper if $p < 0$ since the integrand is not defined at $t=0$ in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $-2 < p <0$, using $\sin t \leq t$, we have
\begin{align*}
I_p & = \int_0^1 t^p \sin t \ dt \\
& \leq \int_0^1 t^{1+ p}  \ dt \\
& \leq \frac{1}{p + 2} < \infty.
\end{align*}
Hence, the integral converges for $-2 < p < 0$. For $p \leq -2$, first note that $\sin t \geq t/2$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
I_p & = \int_0^1 t^p \sin t \ dt \\
& \geq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 t^{(1+ p)}  \ dt.
\end{align*}
Since the integral on RHS diverges for $p \leq -2$, $I_p$ also diverges.

Comment: beautiful. How did you get the clue for $p\leqslant 2, \sin t\geqslant \frac{t}{2}$ ? Can you share the idea ?

Comment: I don't know if I would call it a "trick" exactly. It is a pretty standard approach to find a lower bound of integrand. Since behaviour near zero is what is crucial, the idea is to take a polynomial approximation close to 0 that is valid for your interval.